# Active mq multiple consumers working in parallel

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

The JMS contract is that only 1 session is used by one thread at once

resource: http://activemq.apache.org/multiple-consumers-on-a-queue.html

As you can see in image for every consumer session id is one. Is it ok to have, and how to check if my consumers are consuming one at a time or they are working in parallel?

Is session id same for each consumer is a right configuration?

[image: The image is from web console, for every consumer session id is one]

Answer (score 0):

Just let your consumers print out a message and see that they are working in parallel. 
Use an instance number on each consumer instead.

Comment: is the sessionid for each consumer to be 1; a ok configuration?

Comment: Don't rely on it since you're always get 1 according to your question.  Do what I wrote and then you will see if it is working in parallel.

Comment: I know AMQ is capable of working in parallel.  It is just to make sure your client does everything as it should

Answer (score 0):

It appears you've created 4 separate connections and a consumer session from each of those 4 connections. By default, the first session created from a connection will have an id of 1. So in your case, its fine that all 4 sessions have the same id because they pertain to difference connections. To determine how the broker is balancing the message load across all 4 consumer objects, you can view the relevant metrics via either the web or JMX console. If all 4 consumers are consuming from the same queue, then keep in mind the default prefetch limit.

Comment: in that case if I have four different queue, then all 4 different queue can be consumed by any of four consumer . Is my understanding correct?